# Oracle ALL on SUBQUERY

Tags: sql, oracle

I have simple question about Corelated Sub-Query:

The tables and data is as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE AUTHORS
(
   NAME  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)  
);

Insert into AUTHORS Values ('john');
Insert into AUTHORS Values ('bill');
Insert into AUTHORS Values ('dave');


 CREATE TABLE BOOKS
 (
   NAME   VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
   PRICE  INTEGER
 );


Insert into BOOKS Values ('john', 101);
Insert into BOOKS Values ('john', 200);
Insert into BOOKS Values ('john', 300);
insert into books values ('bill', 200 );
Insert into BOOKS Values ('bill', 10);
Insert into BOOKS Values ('dave', 5);
COMMIT;
```

Question: here 'john' has all books with price > 100.

But when I use following query, only one row is returned:

```
  select * from
    authors a
     where  100 < all( select price from books b where a.nAME = b.NAME );
```

Comment: there is only 1 record for john in authors table that is y 1 row u r getting

Comment: Only `JOHN` has all bocks with prices >= 100, then only `JOHN` is fetched by the outer query/ The operator `100 < ALL (101,200,300)` is true for `John`, and for `bill` it is false: `100 < ALL( 10 )` because 100 is NOT less than 10, and for `dave` --
> `100 < ALL( 5 )` is  also false because 100 is NOT less than 5. What do you think the query should return ?

Comment: @krokodilko - yes, there is only record in authors table for which all books are over 100. I seemed to have missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all the matched records with books table with given condition then below query will work

```
select * from
    authors a join books c on a.name=c.name
     where  100 < all( select price from books b where a.nAME = b.NAME );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the books for names, where the minimum price is greater than 100, I would simply do:

```
select b.*
from (select b.*, min(b.price) over (partition by b.name) as minprice
      from books b
     ) b
where minprice > 100;
```

If you only wanted the name, I would use aggregation:

```
select b.name
from books b
group by b.name
having min(b.price) > 100;
```

Both of these seem simpler than your approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to return all books for John where price is > 100 then this should do it.

`SELECT * 
FROM authors a
INNER JOIN books b ON a.name = b.name
WHERE a.name = 'john' AND b.price > 100;`